# Sql Table Locked By Readpast

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, locking

I have a SQL View.  I use `READPAST` on this SQL View. Because i don't want to see dirty data. But SQL `READPAST` locked this SQL View 's Table. I don't want to Table locking, i just want to locking Row.

Which method is correct?

Comment: The locks SQL Server uses with your query depends on all the operations of your current transaction and also the actual query you are using together with the view's underlying tables and indexes. For a full answer you will have to include all this info in your question.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will share my query. But first, i will try isolation level.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is isolation level.You must use read committed snapshot if you use sql server.This provides that you fetch only committed data.Also this does not cause table lock.But you must enable it in database level.You can look https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/read-committed-snapshot-isolation-high-version_ghost_record_count/amp/ for configuration.
Also readpast is not a solution.It skips locked rows.So you get missing results.When a row is updated,Your select query ignore this row.But in read committed isolation level you get committed version of this row even if locked by another transaction and
this isolation level does not lock your table.I assume that you use default isolation level for the transaction.if you do not set a isolation level to the transaction it uses default isolation level and this is read committed.Read committed snapshot only works under read committed isolation level without locking.Except this for example in serializable isolation level it continues to lock.So you can use default isolation level for the transaction calling your view.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I will try isolation level.

Comment: When using read committed snapshot,You must be careful about tempdb.For example basically tempdb disk must be in ssd if your concurrent transactions are too much.You can look at https://logicalread.com/sql-server-tempdb-considerations-w02/#.XLR8COgzaUk.

Answer (score 0):

When you select from a table you put a shared lock on it anyway...but if your table is locked and you don't want to see dirty data beside using readpast you should make sure that your table has an index and then set page lock to off and row lock to on..of course your query should have a where clause on on yhe indexed column..
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-2017